# Best way to activate/deactivate two layouts on top of each other in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to put two Linear Layouts containing ImageButtons in my app, where depending on the choice of a spinner, one layout with all its buttons would appear and be "active", while the other layout will be "inactive", meaning you can't see any of its buttons and they obviously won't be visible/clickable.

What's the best way to approach this?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn2"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have seen examples online using relative layout, and placing the two linear layouts inside on relative layout, but is doing that and then manually switching everything inside to be invisible and deactivated the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you are setting visibility=gone for one of them right? personally if it works I dont see why there would be anything wrong with this. I think the layout wouldnt even need to be relative for this to work but i havnt tried

Answer (score 0):

One way is to do that using XML:

`android:visibility="invisible"`

However, you can also do it in the Java (in case you want to make it visible again ):

```
 linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE / VISIBLE / GONE );
```